# Error while adding a foreign key in user.php at FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, foreign-keys, database-schema, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle. I tried to add a foreign key to `User.php` (class User extends BaseUser) but this doesn't work, as it always shows an error. Can you guys please help me? I'm new at using symfony:

User.php:
[image: User.php]

This is the error:
[image: And this is the error]

I'll be grateful guys if you help me, I tried a lot of things and it didn't work.
I'm wondering what would be the reason for this mistake.
Thank you in advance

Here is the code for Equipe.php:

```
 <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Nouha
 * Date: 06/04/2017
 * Time: 16:07
 */

namespace MyApp\EspritBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * Class Equipe
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class Equipe
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $idEq;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */

    private $nomEq;


    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getIdEq()
    {
        return $this->idEq;
    }


    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getNomEq()
    {
        return $this->nomEq;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $nomEq
     */
    public function setNomEq($nomEq)
    {
        $this->nomEq = $nomEq;
    }

}
```

And this is the code for User.php:

```
    <?php
    // src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php

    namespace MyApp\EspritBundle\Entity;


use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="utilisateur")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $RaisonSociale;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $tel;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $tva;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $fax;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $site;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $ville;

    /*
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $cp;

    /**
     *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Equipe")
     *@ORM\JoinColumn(name="idEq", referencedColumnName="idEq")
     */

    private $id_equipe;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */


    public function getRaisonSociale()
    {
        return $this->RaisonSociale;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $RaisonSociale
     */
    public function setRaisonSociale($RaisonSociale)
    {
        $this->RaisonSociale = $RaisonSociale;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCp()
    {
        return $this->cp;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $cp
     */
    public function setCp($cp)
    {
        $this->cp = $cp;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFax()
    {
        return $this->fax;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $fax
     */
    public function setFax($fax)
    {
        $this->fax = $fax;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTel()
    {
        return $this->tel;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $tel
     */
    public function setTel($tel)
    {
        $this->tel = $tel;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTva()
    {
        return $this->tva;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $tva
     */
    public function setTva($tva)
    {
        $this->tva = $tva;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getSite()
    {
        return $this->site;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $site
     */
    public function setSite($site)
    {
        $this->site = $site;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getVille()
    {
        return $this->ville;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $ville
     */
    public function setVille($ville)
    {
        $this->ville = $ville;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getIdEquipe()
    {
        return $this->id_equipe;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id_equipe
     */
    public function setIdEquipe($id_equipe)
    {
        $this->id_equipe = $id_equipe;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not images. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: I'm new in here, I did it, thank you. I guess now it would be easy for you to see where I did a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys,

I found the answer for my own question,

I just had to add this function:

```
public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can try something like that :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Equipe")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false) // Optional
 */
private $equipe;
```

Also, idEq should be of type int and primary key I think.

Good luck.

Comment: I put it as nullable and I tried to put a picture for the Equipe Entity but because I'm new, StackoverFlow didn't allow me more than 2 pics:

Comment: Here is the code for IdEq in Equipe.php:

 
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $idEq;